# Unity Virtual Reality: Question about input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I am trying to achieve at this point, is the following:
Let's say that we have a Cube game object and a SteamVR player.
The Cube object is on position y = 100 and the SteamVR player is on position y = 0.

I want to make it possible that the player can zoom in on the game object by doing the following:

-> Pressing both triggers and bringing the controllers close to each other will zoom in.

-> Pressing both triggers and bringing the controllers away from each other will zoom out.

I think u understand the effect that I want to create.

For my project I am using the SteamVR Unity plugin.

Could someone say me if this is possible and give me some insight on how to do this?

Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 1):

Have an if statement checking for two inputs and move the camera position in the forward direction close and closer to the target. If you want to save the original camera position before zooming just store the Camera.main.forward before incrementing it.

**pseudocode**

```
public SteamVR_Input_Sources LeftInputSource = SteamVR_Input_Sources.LeftHand;
public SteamVR_Input_Sources RightInputSource = SteamVR_Input_Sources.RightHand;              
public Vector3 currentZoom;
public Vector3 zoomAmount;

void update(){
    if( SteamVR_Actions._default.Squeeze.GetAxis(LeftInputSource) && SteamVR_Actions._default.Squeeze.GetAxis(RightInputSource)){
currentZoom.forward += zoomAmount.forward; //increment zoom by whatever amount while 
triggers are held
Camera.main.transform.forward = currentZoom;
    }
}
```

I have not tested this, hence why I labeled it pseudocode, however, I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. If I call getAxes on either the left or right hand. It gives me value 1 if I am pressing the trigger?

Comment: Yeah it is just giving me the value of how far the trigger is pressed. Value from 0 to 1.

Comment: Hmm, maybe check this thread out on the Unity forums, its a good starting point! :)  https://forum.unity.com/threads/vive-controller-trigger-press.567997/ You could perhaps do something interesting if its measuring how far the trigger is being pressed, maybe that determines how far the camera goes forward? That would be cool!

Comment: Yeah well, I got the first step of what I want. I can detect when both triggers are fully pressed. Then I really need to get the zooming working. Like how it works on a mobile device. The further your fingers get, the more u zoom out. The closer your finger get, the more u zoom in. Only, I did not figure out how to do this as of yet.